# Lagging silverlight app

Tags: silverlight

I've been playing around with Silverlight 5 and started putting together a little game. It's nothing special and it's purely to just play around.

If you look at the link below you'll notice that it's lagging a bit.

Link(Just use the arrow keys): http://www.netauto.co.za/WIP/GameTest.html

Basically I'm using a Storyboard to scroll the road and move the cars on the screen with every tick. At first I used the CompositionTarget.Rendering, but I was having the same problem. So I thought I'll try a Storyboard, but it made no difference.

There is a second timer that adds a vehicle in a random lane with every tick. They get removed once they go off screen. Disabling this timer makes no difference.

CPU usage is almost none. Also tried it on another PC and it was exactly the same.

I would post some code, but there's quite a bit of it and as I'm just fooling around it's a bit of a mess 0.o

Any ideas on how I can move the objects around without that lag?

I'm using Silverlight 5.

Thank you

Comment: I tried this basic example: http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/silverlight-speed-loop/

The experience is the same though. Maybe it's just a Silverlight thing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [BitmapCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.bitmapcache%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) on the scrolling road and cars, if you are not already. This *can* cut down on the traffic to the GPU.

More links: [One](http://www.andybeaulieu.com/Home/tabid/67/EntryID/144/Default.aspx), [Two](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309563%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't seem make a difference though.